# How to split object key and convert it into array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, destructuring

i'm facing issue to convert object into array of object. i'm having object like,

```
const employeeDetails = {
  "admin-name": "deepak",
  "admin-age": "29",
  "tester-name": "raju",
  "tester-age": "26",
};
```

i'm expecting format like,

```
 const employeeDetails = [
  {
    _id: "admin",
    name: "deepak",
    age: 29,
  },
  {
   _id: "tester",
   name: "raju",
   age: 26,
  },
];
```

Comment: provide your attempt to solve problem.

Comment: You forgot somehow to post the code you're having issues with. Please take a [tour], read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const employeeDetails = {
  "admin-name": "deepak",
  "admin-age": "29",
  "tester-name": "raju",
  "tester-age": "26",
}

const employeeArray = Object
  .entries(employeeDetails)
  .map(([key, value]) => {
    const [_id, attribute] = key.split('-')
    return {
      _id,
      [attribute]: value
    }
  })
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur._id] ??= { _id: cur._id }
    Object.assign(acc[cur._id], cur)
    return acc
  }, {})

const result = Object.values(employeeArray)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const employeeDetails = {
  "admin-name": "deepak",
  "admin-age": "29",
  "tester-name": "raju",
  "tester-age": "26",
};

const resultObj = Object.entries(employeeDetails).reduce(
  (acc, [key, value]) => {
    const dashIndex = key.indexOf('-');
    const parts = [key.slice(0, dashIndex), key.slice(dashIndex+1)];
    
    acc[parts[0]] ??= { _id: parts[0] };
    acc[parts[0]][parts[1]] = value;
    return acc;
  }
, {});

const resultArr = Object.values(resultObj);

console.log(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const employeeDetails = {
  "admin-name": "deepak",
  "admin-age": "29",
  "tester-name": "raju",
  "tester-age": "26",
}

const restoreRecords = (from) => {
  const records = new Map();
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(from)) {
    const segmented = key.split("-");
    if (segmented.length === 2) {
      const record = records.get(segmented[0]);
      if (typeof record === "undefined") {
        const payload = {
          _id: segmented[0],
          [segmented[1]]: value,
        };
        records.set(payload._id, payload);
      } else {
        record[segmented[1]] = value;
      }
    }
  }
  return [...records.values()];
};

console.log(restoreRecords(employeeDetails));
```